# Average cost / algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, average

I know this true or false statement below is false. Since Θ(log n) is the amortized cost. But can we somehow determine the average cost from this question, how? If not what do we need to determine the average cost?

Statement

True or false:
A data structure supports an operation f such that a sequence of n operations f takes
Θ(n log n) time in the worst case. Hence, the average-case cost of an f operation is Θ(log n).

Comment: It's true I think, you just divide the cost of the sequence by the number of calls of that operations.

Comment: But isnt that the amortized cost? If every operation cost log n so we have n*log n / n =  Θ(log n). Maybe i miss understood amortized cost also.

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question because the wording is ambiguous. Specifically, what is the "average" in the "average-case" over? If it's the average over the operations that form the worst case, then the statement is true. But that's not normally what's meant by "average case", where "average" is over some distribution of inputs (often all inputs assuming each are equally likely) and the average-case may be better than theta(log n).

Comment: @Busquets_90 I'd read it like this, you have a data structure with an operation `f` you call `f` n times and the total cost of these calls is `O(n*log(n))`.  The amortized is an average by definition. If you read Cormen's book that's how it's defined (unless you use a different reference).

Comment: Thank you for the advice about Cormen's book. It says like this about Amortized analysis: "Amortized analysis differs
from average-case analysis in that probability is not involved;  ##an amortized analysis
guarantees the average performance of each operation in the worst case## " Isnt this the case here?

Comment: @Busquets_90 So the difference between the probabilistic analysis is that when you do the computation you also multiply for the probability of that instance to happen. In the amortized analysis instead you actually assume a deterministic sequence of the same operation, and you just average out (literally arithmetic mean). The meaning is indeed different, if you look at Cormen's book and see the quicksort analysis that's different from the ammortized analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The intended answer to this question is probably "true".  If the total cost of n operations is Θ(n log n), then you can divide by n to get the average cost, Θ(log n).

The question is a little confusing, though, because it says a "sequence of n operations f".  It's possible that the data structure could support other operations that change how much time operation f would take, and therefore timing a sequence of operations f doesn't necessarily tell you the average cost of f if other operations are allowed... but the questioner probably just not considering that.

The *amortized* cost of operation f is different from the average, because part of the amortized cost may be paid by *other* operations.  The time taken by operation f can therefore provide a lower bound on its amortized cost, but it tells you nothing about any upper bound.

Comment: So the upper bound for the amortized cost could be n^3 for example if we had one operation that has O(n^3) in the worst-case?

Comment: Consider a priority queue implemented by sorting:  addItem() appends to the list in constant time, and removeMinimum() sorts the list if it's not sorted and then removes in constant time.  You could give the costs of addItem and removeMinimum as O(1) and O(n log n), or you could give their amortized costs as O(n log n) and O(1), since a sequence of removeMinimum are all O(1) if there are no adds.

Comment: Well i think i get you now. If we have this case then:   

"  If the amortized cost of every operation on a data structure is O(1), then the running time
of any sequence of m operations on such an initially empty data structure is O(m2) in the
worst case. "

Could we guarantee a worst case of O(m^2), because a sequence of m operations could make it worse then?